# c++ How to initialize an array inside a class object?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
class Node {
public:
    float point[3];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float p[3] = { 34, 90, 10 };
    Node *node = new Node();
    node->point = p;
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work as expected.

How should I initialize an array of a class object?

Comment: Use `std::array<float, 3>` instead

Comment: What happened to constructors? And using the right *storage durations*?

Comment: You have a memory leak.

Comment: @StoryTeller for 'float point[3]'? or for 'float p[3]'?

Comment: Both. Better yet, `using point_t = std::array<float, 3>;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array != pointer.

```
error: invalid array assignment
     node->point = p;
```

Here is the correct way to copy the array:

```
std::copy(std::begin(p),std::end(p), std::begin(node->point));
```

---

If you know the size of the array at compile time, you should use `std::array`:

```
class Node {
public:
    std::array<float,3> point;
};

std::array<float,3> p = {34.0f, 90.0f, 10.0f};
node->point = p;
```

Also, you may initialize the array via constructor and leave `point` as `private` data member:

```
// Ctor
Node(std::array<float,3> p) { point = p; }

// Calling
Node *node = new Node({34.0f, 90.0f, 10.0f});
// Or
std::array<float,3> p = {34.0f, 90.0f, 10.0f};
Node *node = new Node(p);
```

Otherwise, if you want to choose the size of the array at runtime, you should use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

When using your design, you must copy the values as Node reserves memory.

Whether your approach is a good practise is an other question. Initializing from outside is somewhat strange

```
class Node {
  public:
    float point[3];
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  float p[3] = { 34, 90, 10 };
  Node *node = new Node();
  memcpy (node->point, p, sizeof(p));
  return 0;
}

// alternative version

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  Node *node = new Node();
  node->point[0] = 34.0f;
  node->point[1] = 90.0f;
  node->point[2] = 10.0f;

  return 0;
}
```